# How to verify valid email address in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with email field and like 30K records..
I discovered that many users has entered invalid email addresses with chars like :
`<,@@` etc...

Is there a way in PostgreSQL to run a query which will shows all invalid email address? I know how to do that with regular expressions

```
[a-z,A-z,0-9,'.']*@[a-z,A-z,0-9]*.com
```

`[a-z,A-z,0-9,'.']*@[a-z,A-z,0-9]*.xx|xxx.xx`   for address like `.co.uk` or `.org.it`

How can this be done in a query?
I just want to get a list of all invalid address so I can ask to fix their records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [POSIX regexp functionality](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) of PostgreSQL:

Have a query with the following condition (`email` is your email column) in your where clause:

`where email !~* '^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]+$'`

Or whatever regular expression works for you.

Comment: an address like example.com is considered valid with this regex

Comment: The question is more about how to execute regex matching, not the particular regex.